# Django ImageField "Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image."

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have PIL installed, however whenever I try to upload a .png file to an image field through the Django Admin for my model, I get this error:

"Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image."

Other image types work fine. I have tried several different PNG files.

I have tried rebuilding PIL after installing pypng, libpng-dev, etc.. and am on ubuntu server.

Comment: When you install PIL, have you made sure that it see's your libpng etc. and confirms that is has PNG compatibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compile PIL it should say if it has been compiled with PNG support or not, but if you have problems installing it yourself, I would recommend that you use the version that comes with ubuntu. It's strangely named but easily installed with:

```
apt-get install python-imaging
```

Comment: I need to install inside virtual env.

Answer (score 7):

This issue was solved by using pip to install "pillow" instead of "pil" which allows easy deployment to virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that building PIL on Ubuntu can cause problems because `libpng` is in a non standard location, and PIL can't find it.

In the folder that PIL has been downloaded to, edit `setup.py`. Find the following line:

```
JPEG_ROOT = None
```

and change it to

```
JPEG_ROOT = '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/'
```

then rebuild PIL and check for the messages near the end that PNG support is included.

I know it's odd to modify `JPEG_ROOT` when you want to add PNG support, but `setup.py` will look in `JPEG_ROOT` for `libpng` too.