# PUT multipart-formdata containing PNG with XMLHttpRequest in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, django, xmlhttprequest, png

I'm trying to PUT svg, a string and a png together to a Django REST api from a pure javascript client.

I'm currently stuck with error 400 *"Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image."* response from the backend.

The png is created with the Pablo-svg-library, which converts the svg to png (With "toImage()").

The file itself doesn't appear to be corrupt, it can be loaded with python pillow (Which is also used by Django's ImageField).

```js
var file = new Blob([svgData], { type: 'text/xml'});
var img = Pablo(document.getElementById('stage')).toImage('png', appendImgToFormAndSend);

function appendImgToFormAndSend() {
    var picture = new Blob([img[0].src], { type: 'image/png'});

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("PUT", "http://myapi.local/upload_all_the_data");

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('picture', picture, 'picture1.png')
    formData.append('rawdata', file, 'rawdata');
    formData.append('url', location.href);

    xhr.send(formData)
};

xhr.onload = function() {
                console.log("ANSWER");
                console.log(this.responseText);
                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                console.log(data)
            }
```

Have I got a conceptual misunderstanding here?

Uploading the identical file through Django's admin template works fine (Although the raw-data of the png in the request looks quite different), so I assume the error-response above is misleading and the issue is with the request/encoding/filetype.

The payload from the js-code above looks like this:

```
-----------------------------1331527982888194116440756954

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture"; filename="picture1.png"

Content-Type: image/png



data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgAAAGQCAYAA [snip]
-----------------------------1331527982888194116440756954

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rawdata"; filename="rawdata"

Content-Type: text/xml



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 400">
<text x="193.17" y="104.88" font-size="30px" style="stroke: black; fill: rgb(111, 126, 14);">Hello World</text>
<rect x="128.24" y="135.89" width="89.22" height="14.74" style="stroke: black; fill: rgb(69, 214, 137);"></rect>
<circle cx="287.04" cy="166.81" r="44.18" style="stroke: black; fill: rgb(39, 203, 202);"></circle>
<circle cx="69.34" cy="41.28" r="56.59" style="stroke: black; fill: rgb(140, 165, 11);"></circle>
<text x="480.22" y="21.02" font-size="30px" style="stroke: black; fill: rgb(127, 87, 191);">Hello World</text>
</svg>

-----------------------------1331527982888194116440756954

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="url"



http://myurl:8080/svg_editor/index.html?pk=5978bc3a-a275-4114-94a5-f90063ba3641

-----------------------------1331527982888194116440756954--
```

The request's payload from Django's admin template in contrast is encoded.

Comment: have you tried this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606614/django-imagefield-upload-a-valid-image-the-file-you-uploaded-was-either-not-an

Comment: @Anatsu Yes, thank you. Uploading the same png through the django admin template works fine. I therefore assume it's connected to how I build the request.

Answer (score 1):

The png I tried to PUT is represented in a [data uri scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). The way I created the Blob above is not correct. The raw data of the png first needs to be extracted from the data uri and only then can it be inserted in a Blob, together with the mimedata.

How this conversion is done properly has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5100158/570722

(I'm not including the given code-example here as it might change in the future and this highly-upvoted answer is more likely to be updated).

I also stated above that the png was correctly loaded with Pillow - however the png I tested was retrieved through the output of the developer-console. There the data uri was converted to an actual image by the browser - in conclusion I never tested the "image"-data that was uploaded to the backend (Which still was a data uri), but instead I tested an already decoded png.